# Pass variables to template using hook_block_view_alter()

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm trying the change the homepage path based on the current request. The `system_main_block` block renders the logo which is linked to the homepage. If the current path starts with `/foo/...`, I want to change the homepage path to point to `/foo` instead of the default `/`.

I want to pass a custom variable to a block using `hook_block_view_alter()`.

The hook gives me the build array and the Block itself as arguments.

How can I add a variable to the build array that I can then access in the view (twig template)?

The build array looks like this:

```
array
    '#theme' => string 'block'
    '#attributes' => 
        array (size=0)
        empty
    '#contextual_links' => 
        ...
    '#weight' => int -3
    '#configuration' => 
        array (size=4)
            'id' => string 'system_main_block' (length=17)
            'label' => string 'Main page content' (length=17)
            'provider' => string 'system' (length=6)
            'label_display' => string '0' (length=1)
    '#plugin_id' => string 'system_main_block' (length=17)
    '#base_plugin_id' => string 'system_main_block' (length=17)
    '#derivative_plugin_id' => null
    '#id' => string 'my_id' (length=19)
    '#pre_render' => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string 'Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender' (length=40)
    '#block' => 
        object(Drupal\block\Entity\Block)[3592]
```

I can't see where I can assign an extra variable. Am using the wrong hook?

Comment: Can you explain what your end goal is?

Comment: @Jaypan I updated the description.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better option is to override `PathProcessorFront::processOutbound()`:

```
 public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    // The special path '<front>' links to the default front page.
    if ($path === '/<front>') {
      $path = '/';
    }
    return $path;
```

Overriding in this case means using a similar outbound pathprocessor with a higher priority and replace `'/<front>'` or a lower priority and replace `'/'`.

**Edit:**

Register the path processor as a service with the tag `path_processor_outbound` in mymodule.services.yml. This is the core service definition from the example before:

```
path_processor_front:
    class: Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 200 }
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
```

Comment: Hi 4k4, I can use [PathProcessorManager::addOutbound](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21PathProcessorManager.php/function/PathProcessorManager%3A%3AaddOutbound/8.2.x) to register a new Processor, but where should I add the code in my module? Should I add an event subscriber for a KernelEvent?

Comment: @Tim, this is a service with the tag path_processor_outbound, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

The `system_main_block` is not the place to be looking. Whilst it's not a block in the traditional sense. Your logo position, and the URL it links to, are probably controlled by your theme. It should be simple to pass an updated URL as a custom variable in the theme.